# Undefined method 'menu'

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

hi im new in ROR development im just wondering why my app rise a

```
"undefined method `menu'
```

i seems to associate my models right

i would like to show a menu that the reservation reserverd and show its recipes inside that menu but it rises undefiend method 'menu'

package_line_item.rb

```
  belongs_to :menu
  belongs_to :reservation
```

reservation.rb

```
  has_one :reservation_package
  belongs_to :service
  has_many :reservation_function_rooms
  has_many :package_line_items
  has_many :menus , :through => :package_line_items, :uniq => true
  has_many :function_rooms, :through =>:reservation_function_rooms
```

menu.rb

```
has_many :package_line_items
has_many :menu_recipes
has_many :recipes, :through => :menu_recipes, :uniq => true
belongs_to :menu_category
```

package_line_item_controller.rb

```
 def index 
    @package_line_items = PackageLineItems.all
  end


  def show
     @reservation = Reservation.includes(:package_line_items => :menu).find(params[:id])
  end


  def new  
    @reservation = Reservation.find(params[:reservation_id])
    @package_line_item = @reservation.package_line_items.build
  end

  def create
  @reservation = Reservation.find(params[:reservation_id])
  @reservation.package_line_items.build(params[:package_line_item])

    if @package_line_item.save
      redirect_to @reservation ,:notice => "added menu"
    end
```

routes.rb

```
 resources :services

  resources :reservations do
     resources :reservation_packages
     resources :reservation_function_rooms
     resources :packages 
     resources :package_line_items
     resources :package_crews

  end

  resources :function_rooms

  resources :crews



  resources :menu_categories

  resources :menus do
     resources :menu_recipes
   end

  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config

  resources :recipe_categories

  resources :recipes
```

package_line_item/show.html.erb

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>    
<%= @reservation.package_line_items.menu.name%>
```

if other file is needed feel free to ask me thank you more power to us thanks

Answer (score 0):

It might be because "menu" is a method in the ActiveAdmin DSL. I had a problem with a model called "Page" precisely for this reason. Try renaming your model and see what happens.